# how can I create Class object using Reflection in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, reflection

I have a project Car with multiple classes A.cs, B.cs , I have created its one.dll and add it to another project CarDate..

How can I create object of all .cs file in project Car (e.g A.cs) in project CarDate using reflection?

Comment: Why do you need reflection for this? Reference the assembly where `A` is located and create instances of that type. For all the other types accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact, I do not understand your goals, you could try something similar to code below.

```
var carAssembly  = typeof (/* any type from Car project */).Assembly;
var types = carAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericType);
var objects = types.Select(Activator.CreateInstance);
```

It will work just for some kinds of types declared in your project (I've filtered all which are not abstract or generic classes) and only if all the classes found have default constructors. You could modify it yourself a bit. 
Btw, there is no universal solution for such a task.